# Area preserving diffeomorphisms of surfaces with only hyperbolic periodic points

Tags: ds.dynamical-systems, sg.symplectic-geometry

This is a (probably very naive question) about area-preserving maps of surfaces.

Does there exist a Hamiltonian diffeomorphism
$$ f: \Sigma \to \Sigma $$
of a symplectic surface (real dimension $2$), possibly with boundary $\partial \Sigma$, such that $f|_{\partial \Sigma} = id$, and such that all periodic points of $f$ in the interior of $\Sigma$ are hyperbolic in the sense if $x$ is a periodic point, i.e. $f^n(x) = x$, then $d(f^n): T_x\Sigma \to T_x\Sigma$ has no eigenvalues on the unit circle?

If one exists, what is a simple construction of such an $f$?

Comment: If you change the manifold